Did not / Do not think ... could
I came across this question, with three choices as the possible answers. The answer sheet says a) is correct, but it seems to me that both a) and b) are correct, depending on what meaning you want to convey.

I .... (not think) she could arrive in time.
a) didn't think
b) don't think
c) haven't thought

Can there be a reason why a is a better choice than b, maybe? Or is the question just wrong?
Thank you

For c, I'd need I hadn't thought ... but then she surprised me. First I thought No, then she proved me wrong. So a is much simpler.

It's a stupid test, because there's nothing inherently wrong with [I] don't think he could do [something] (that's a link to probably hundreds of published instances of that combination of tenses). But obviously the test-setter is thinking that past tense could (matching Present Tense can) is more likely to fit better with past tense didn't think. Test setters who fail to take account of (or provide) context shouldn't be in that job.

The testers usually have something in mind. Here, it's the could as past tense. They're surely thinking this: I don't think I can arrive on time. I didn't think I could arrive on time. Those are just two standard sentences. Whereas: I don't think I could arrive on time. is fine but slightly more "advanced...

In my mind, A is correct. B would be understood but "I don't think she would arrive in time." is better.

You can't pick the right words if you don't know the intended meaning. Don't worry about it, unless the test has high stakes.

You typically don't use the Simple Past could to refer to singular actions that you were capable of, but rather skills and overall capabilities - I could read when I was three, but not ?I could catch that train, but I was able to catch that train instead. (The "?" sentence isn't incorrect, but it uses could in a different, hypothetical sense, not as a Simple Past of can). With didn't, could becomes a prospective, future-in-the-past form, which makes it acceptable in either usage.


I ... (not think) she could arrive in time.

Both (a) and (b) are possible.
There are lots of matches for do not think * could.
Examples of such constructions are readily found, like I don't think she could make it and "I don't think she could escape".
